# Given the sequence of real numbers with the restrictions $0<x_n<1$ and $(1-x_n)x_{n+1}>\frac{1}{4}$, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given the sequence of real numbers with the restrictions $0<x_n<1$ and $(1-x_n)x_{n+1}>\frac{1}{4}$, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\frac{1}{2}$.

I am having trouble approaching this problem since it does not give an explicit recursive formula.

I would like to say that the sequence is strictly increasing and perhaps find a bound, but in terms of computation it is hard for me to work with.

Thanks

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693184/convergence-of-a-sequence-with-0a-n1.

Answer (score 3):

We know $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: (x_n-1/2)^2\geq 0$, hence $x_n^2-x_n+1/4\geq 0$, so $1/4\geq x_n-x_n^2$, i.e. $1\geq 4(x_n-x_n^2)$, or equivalently $\frac{1}{4(x_n-x_n^2)}\geq 1$ (note that $x_n-x_n^2>0$, as $0<x_n<1$).

We are given that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}: (1-x_n)x_{n+1}>1/4$, hence, dividing by $1-x_n>0$: $x_{n+1}>\frac{1}{4(1-x_n)}$. Divide this by $x_n>0$: $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}> \frac{1}{4(x_n-x_n^2)}$. The last member is, as we found out earlier, greater or equal to $1$. Hence we have $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}>1$, i.e. $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is increasing.

As  $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded (by $1$), it must converge to some $l\in [0,1]$ (we know that $l$ is in this interval, because the sequence only lives between $0$ and $1$).

Now, taking the limit on the given inequality: $\lim_{n\to +\infty} (1-x_n)x_{n+1}\geq 1/4$ (note that you always need to replace $>$ by $\geq$ in the limit). Hence: $(1-l)l\geq 1/4$, so $-l^2+l-1/4 \geq 0$, i.e. $l^2-l+1/4 \leq 0$. The left member equals $(l-1/2)^2$, so we obtain $(l-1/2)^2 \leq 0$. Thus $l=1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

hint: suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=l$ exists

so $$(1-x_n)x_{n+1}>\frac{1}{4}\\(1-l)l>\frac{1}{4}\\4-4l^2>1\\4l^2-4l<-1\\4l^2-4l+1<0\\(2l-1)^2<0$$ that is impossible...if only $(2l-1)^2 \to 0$

Comment: The inequality in the second line must be weak: $\;(1-l)l\ge\frac14\;$

Comment: That's the easy part. The hard part is showing that the limit exists.